# OpenGL superbible access violation

Tags: opengl

Well, I've searched a bit around and the only advice I see people really giving is kind of ambiguous, slightly outdated drivers possibly (mine is the latest Geforce G210m mobile driver). Anyways, I'm just learning OpenGL and having learned some XNA, I feel this will be a good balance but I could do without having such frustration in the beginning.

Anyways, I'm simply using the source straight from Triangle.cpp. I am getting:

*Unhandled exception at 0x00000000 in OOGL.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation.*

Right after the call to triangleBatch.Begin().

Can anyone tell me straight forwardly what is up and how to alleviate this?

Here is the source:

```
// Triangle.cpp
// Our first OpenGL program that will just draw a triangle on the screen.

#include <GLTools.h>            // OpenGL toolkit
#include <GLShaderManager.h>    // Shader Manager Class

#ifdef __APPLE__
#include <glut/glut.h>          // OS X version of GLUT
#else
#define FREEGLUT_STATIC
#include <GL/glut.h>            // Windows FreeGlut equivalent
#endif

GLBatch triangleBatch;
GLShaderManager shaderManager;

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Window has changed size, or has just been created. In either case, we need
// to use the window dimensions to set the viewport and the projection matrix.
void ChangeSize(int w, int h)
    {
    glViewport(0, 0, w, h);
    }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// This function does any needed initialization on the rendering context. 
// This is the first opportunity to do any OpenGL related tasks.
void SetupRC()
    {
    // Blue background
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f );

    shaderManager.InitializeStockShaders();

    // Load up a triangle
    GLfloat vVerts[] = { -0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 
                          0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
                          0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f };

    triangleBatch.Begin(GL_TRIANGLES, 3);
    triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vVerts);
    triangleBatch.End();
    }



///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Called to draw scene
void RenderScene(void)
    {
    // Clear the window with current clearing color
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT | GL_STENCIL_BUFFER_BIT);

    GLfloat vRed[] = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
    shaderManager.UseStockShader(GLT_SHADER_IDENTITY, vRed);
    triangleBatch.Draw();

    // Perform the buffer swap to display back buffer
    glutSwapBuffers();
    }


///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// Main entry point for GLUT based programs
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
    {
    gltSetWorkingDirectory(argv[0]);

    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGBA | GLUT_DEPTH | GLUT_STENCIL);
    glutInitWindowSize(800, 600);
    glutCreateWindow("Triangle");
    glutReshapeFunc(ChangeSize);
    glutDisplayFunc(RenderScene);

    GLenum err = glewInit();
    if (GLEW_OK != err) {
        fprintf(stderr, "GLEW Error: %s\n", glewGetErrorString(err));
        return 1;
        }

    SetupRC();

    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Check that the OpenGL extensions used by {{{GLBatch}}} are supported by your GPU.

Comment: Where does it die in the debugger?

Comment: triangleBatch.CopyVertexData3f(vVerts);

Answer (score 0):

By looking at the code of GLBatch, and looking at the error, it is almost certain that either the GL_ARB_vertex_array_object or GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object extension is missing on your computer. The code doesn't check, so that is why it falls.

Sollution? If it fails in GLBatch.cpp at the line where glGenVertexArrays() is called, simply #define OPENGL_ES at the beginning of the file, it will disable vertex array objects and everything will be fine (it is a new extension and it might not be supported by your GPU). In case it fails at glGenBuffers(), then there is probably no code remedy. You need to make sure that you have the latest graphics card drivers and that the GL_ARB_vertex_buffer_object extension is supported (you can use [OpenGL Extension Viewer](http://www.realtech-vr.com/glview/)).